# Django template variable default value not working

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using Django 3.2

I am passing a boolean flag to a Javascript function in my base template. However, when the variable is set, it seems the default value is still being used in my template logic.

Here is my code snippet:

##### /path/to/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
                # ...
                path('foo', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="foo.html", extra_context={'show_subscription_popup':0}), name='blog'),   

                path('admin/', admin.site.urls),                  
              ]
```

##### /path/to/foo.html

```
{% block content %}
<span>{{ show_subscription_popup}}</span>
{% endblock content %}

{% block body_js %}
<script type="text/js">
    $().ready(function() {
        let popDisplayed = '0';

        if ({{ show_subscription_popup|default:1 }}){
            popDisplayed =  getCookie('popDisplayed');
        } 

        /* remaining logic ... */
    });
</script>
```

When I render the page, I see that the variable `show_subscription_popup` has the correct value of 0, which it is passed to the TemplateView, however, in the javascript, the code reads like this:

```
if (1){
   /* do something */
}
```

Why is the default value overwriting the value I passed to the template, and how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: See [Rendering into JavaScript (django-antipatterns)](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/rendering-into-javascript.html). Note: I have authored _this_ specific anti-pattern (and the website itself belongs to another SO user [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of your `show_subscription_popup` variable is `0`. It is stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#default) that:

> If value evaluates to **False**, uses the given default. Otherwise,
> uses the value.

And if you see `bool(0)` is `False`, i.e. `0` is a *falsey* value in python (In fact `False` is actually just a `0`), hence your default of `1` is rendered.

Note that this rendering into JavaScript is a bad practice and makes you **vulnerable** to XSS attacks!! Instead I would do something like the follows:

```
{% block content %}
<span id="show-subscription-popup" data-show-popup="{{ show_subscription_popup}}">{{ show_subscription_popup}}</span>
{% endblock content %}

{% block body_js %}
<script type="text/js">
    $().ready(function() {
        let popDisplayed = '0';
        let showPopup = $("#show-subscription-popup").attr("data-show-popup");
        if (showPopup.length == 0) {
            showPopup = "1";
        }
        showPopup = parseInt(showPopup);
        if (showPopup){
            popDisplayed =  getCookie('popDisplayed');
        } 

        /* remaining logic ... */
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you take a look at my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68437095/django-cbv-form-submission-returned-json-is-displayed-as-a-new-page)?. I have an expiring bounty on it, but no useful answer submitted yet.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `0` is a Falsy value in python, so `show_subscription_popup` is False and the default value is used instead.

Falsy values:

- Empty lists []
- Empty tuples ()
- Empty dictionaries {}
- Empty sets set()
- Empty strings ""
- Empty ranges range(0)
- Zero of any numeric type.
- Integer: 0
- Float: 0.0
- Complex: 0j
- None
- False

Answer (score 1):

As [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#default) template tag documentation states:

> If value **evaluates to False**, uses the given default. Otherwise, uses
> the value.